# Detectar al momento lo introducido en un Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un programa que consista en un solo Entry().

La cosa es que quiero que detecte al momento lo que hay escrito y actue de una manera u otra. Osea que cuando termines de poner el último caracter de por ejemplo "añadir", haga una cosa.

Lo he intentado con la la funcion *.get()* en un *if* pero no hay manera.

Aquí va el código:

```
general.set("Pon ayuda para poder ayudarte")

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"es-ES") #Establecemos región como "España"

dt = datetime.datetime.now() #Sacamos la hora y la fecha del sistema
fecha = dt.strftime("%x") #Establecemos la variable 'fecha' y 'hora' como la 
fecha y la hora actual
hora = dt.strftime("%X")

root.title("Agenda")
root.resizable(1,1)
frame = Frame(root,width=360,height=400,bg="powder blue")
frame.pack(fill="both",expand=1)

entryg = Entry(frame,textvariable=general,bg="powderblue",font= ("",24),justify="center")
entryg.place(x=0,y=0)

if general == "añadir":
    print("si") #Print de comprobación(No funciona)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: podrias publicar el código que has intentado, asi nosotros te podriamos ayudar a indicarte donde esta el problema, y en consecuencia aprenderias más :)

Comment: ¿como indicas que has terminado de escribir?¿presionas un enter o realizas algun otro evento?

Comment: @eyllanesc  Esa es la cosa, que quiero que haga algo sin necesidad de apretar ningún botón. Que termines de escribir y automáticamente lo ejecute

Comment: ¿pero como defines *terminar de escribir*? ¿una pausa larga en la que no presionas ninguna tecla?, y si es asi, cuan larga es la pausa, entiendes, primero define ello.

Comment: por ejemplo como adivinamos que quieres escribir *añadir*, y no *añadiré* o viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que la comprobación se haga automáticamente, es decir, que en el mismo momento en el que el usuario termine de ingresar el último carácter de una cadena determinada en el `Entry` se realice una acción determinada, sin necesidad de que el usuario indique que ha dejado de escribir, la solución es usar el método `trace_add` de la `StringVar` asociada al `Entry` para que se llame a una callback cada vez que el texto es modificado por el usuario:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Agenda")
root.resizable(1, 1)
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=360, height=400, bg="powder blue")
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

general = tk.StringVar()
entryg = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=general, bg="powderblue",
                  font=("",24), justify="center"
                  )

entryg.place(x=0, y=0)

def on_text(*args):
    text = entryg.get().lower()
    if text == "añadir":
        print("Añadir...")
    elif text == "ayuda":
        print("Ayuda...")

general.trace_add("write", on_text)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lógicamente debes ser cuidadoso en la elección de las palabras "clave" para evitar conflictos entre ellas, por ejemplo:

> **ver**
>   **ver**ificar

---

> **Importante:** el método `trace_add` fue [añadido en Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#tkinter) para sustituir a `trace` y `trace_variable`. En caso de usar una versión anterior, se debe usar `trace`.

Si en cambio quieres que la comprobación se realice solo cuando el usuario presione <kbd>ENTER</kbd> en el `Entry` (o cualquier otra tecla) debes usar el método `bind` del `Entry` para asociar el evento a la callback. en el ejemplo anterior sería solo cambiar:

```
general.trace_add("write", on_text)
```

por:

```
entryg.bind("<Return>", on_text)
```

Otra posibilidad sería usar el sistema de validación que incluye el `Entry` usando la opción [`validatecommand`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html), el cual nos permite lanzar una callback (pensada para validar el contenido del `Entry`) ante un evento que indique el fin de la escritura (pulsado de una tecla y pérdida/ganancia del foco básicamente)

Comment: Gracias por todo, pero ¿Me podrías explicar un pelín más a fondo lo del validatecommand?